# Codeigniter 3 destroy session on browser close

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I know there are a lot of questions about "How to destroy the codeigniter session on browser close". But trust me no solution work on not perfect solution like calling ajax request on window unload type.

Is someone have perfect solution for this, i have below configuration for session in config file.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Don't destroy sessions, invalidate them! See the warnings here for more info: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: By having `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;` you're already invalidating the session on browser close. Is this not working for you? by the way, you must have a value for `sess_save_path` otherwise the whole CI session management will be useless

Comment: That said, if what you're looking for is to destroy the session cookie in the browser, there's no need to do it, as the cookie only stores a reference to the session data which is stored on the server, but the session will not persist

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa nope, i replace the native Codeigniter session library by custom session library to use pure PHP session.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;

Comment: check this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html not working already try.

Comment: Why don't you try to do it client side with JavaScript? 
On beforeunload event make an ajax call to the url where you destroy the session.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is sadly, **you can't do this** in the way you'd like.

This is because the server doesn't have an awareness of a the frontend action of closing the browser. The only place to be able to capture this event is in JavaScript, therefore JS has to be your starting point.

From there you may have a few options, you have already discussed a an AJAX request which is the most sensible. You could also just unset the session cookie from JS however that means your server will never know that happened, it'll just not see any more activity on that session until it expires.

**Edit:** also worth noting that unload happens in many situations, closing a tab, hitting the back button etc. So the implementation can get complicated and still be unreliable.

**Edit 2:** You could be really elaborate and set up web sockets on every page to monitor total pages open per user, when the window is unloaded and you have only one connection that's probably the end of the session.

Answer (score 0):

Set $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
I hope it will work